# String swapping around the middle character

Tags: java, string

I have a question regarding a kind of string reversal, but its not full reversal.

If the input is `XYAF` then the output should be `AFXY`. `XY` is the first half and moves to the other side.

If the input is `XYZAF` then the output should be `AFZXY`. `XY` is the first half and moves to the right. `AF` is the second half and moves to the left. `Z` stays in the middle.

How can we do it? I have made a program which is working but I don't think its very efficient. Is there any other way to do it?

```
    String str = "XYAF"; //Output Should be AFXY
    String str1 = "XYZAF"; // Output should be AFZXY

    int length = str1.length();
    int mid = length / 2;
    String output = "" ;
    if (length % 2 == 0) {
        // Even length then divide the string in equal parts
        String x1 = str1.substring(0, mid);
        String x2 = str1.substring(mid, length);
        x3= x2+x1;
    } else {
        // Odd number and we want to
        // xyz and output should be zyx
        String x1 = str1.substring(0, mid);
        String x2 = str1.substring(mid + 1, length);
        x3 = x2 + str1.charAt(mid) + x1;
    }
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: @Jeena you are only showing us part (one example) of your requirements, without being complete in what you need/want and what not ..

Comment: ok, you're right

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about working code belong on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: *i dont think its very efficient*: it is. Why wouldn't it be?

Comment: (Nearly) the most efficient way would be to create a `StringBuilder`, and then use the `StringBuilder.append(CharSequence, int, int)` method.

Comment: Please change the title. This is not string reversal, this is a substring swapping arund a midpoint

Comment: @Stultuske I already mentioned what i want to achieve. Reverse a String. It is mentioned in the question "If Input is like xyaf then output should be afxy" .

Comment: @Jeena yes, but that isn't reversing a String, so saying you want to reverse a String is incorrect.

Comment: Okay agree it is not reversal, Its swapping. Will update the title

Comment: @Jeena this is not a specification. It's ambiguous. Without reading your code, I could deduce from that example that if the input string is ertyuiaf, then the output should be afertyui (for example).

Comment: All fine. `str1.substring(mid + 1, length);` could be abbreviated to `str1.substring(mid + 1);` And `x1` calculated before the if.

Answer (score 1):

You can capitalise on dividing odd/even numbers by 2 by also using a second middle.

```
private String midSwap(String s) {
    // Find the middle rounded down to an integer.
    int mid1 = s.length() / 2;
    // If length is odd then this will be mid1 + 1
    int mid2 = (s.length() + 1) / 2;
    return s.substring(mid2) + s.substring(mid1, mid2) + s.substring(0, mid1);
}

private void test(String s) {
    System.out.println(s + " -> " + midSwap(s));
}

public void test(String[] args) {
    test("XYAF");
    test("XYZAF");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks totally ok and efficient enough.

Maybe you just want to organize it differently:

```
String[] tests = {"XYAF", "XYZAF"};
for (String test : tests) {
   int length = test.length();
   int mid = length / 2;
   String firstHalf = test.substring(0, mid);
   String midPoint = (length % 2 == 0) ? "" : test.substring(mid, mid+1);
   String secondHalf = test.substring(mid + midPoint.length(), length);
   String output = firstHalf + midPoint + secondHalf;
}
```